# Distinction between ranger and randomForest packages/functions?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, supervised-learning

I know that ranger package of random forest is useful in high-dimensional data and it saves computational time and memory compare to the randomForest.

My Question is: Is there any other differences or advantages of one over other that you would like to share?

Comment: In *ranger*, you can compute other kind of rf such as survival random forests.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for sharing